# Retrieve Guice injected 3rd party bean

Tags: spring, guice, openam

I am using forgerock's openam and would like to invoke one of their utilities from my code. The class is defined as follows:

```
@Singleton
public class SessionMaxStats implements StatsListener {

   @Inject
   public SessionMaxStats(
           SessionAccessManager sessionAccessManager,
           MonitoringOperations monitoringOperations,
           SessionNotificationSender sessionNotificationSender,
           Stats stats) {

       this.sessionAccessManager = sessionAccessManager;
       this.monitoringOperations = monitoringOperations;
       this.sessionNotificationSender = sessionNotificationSender;
       this.stats = stats;
   }
```

How can i retrieve this from my application code (via Spring, guice or forgerock libraries)?

Comment: `@Inject SessionMaxStats sms;`?

Comment: I was able to get this using InjectorHolder.getInstance(SessionMaxStats.class)